# Are Arrays in Ada Covariant?

Tags: arrays, ada, covariant

I know in Java arrays are covariant. So for example:

```
Assume Dog is a subclass of Animal
In java the arrays are covariant making: Animal[] a supertype of Dog[]
But in java generic collections are not covariant such as: 
ArrayList<Animal> is not a supertype of ArrayList<Dog>
```

My question is are arrays in Ada Covariant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that by "Animal[] [is] a supertype of Dog[]" you mean that `Animal[42]` might in fact be a `Dog`? If so, then the answer is No.

In Java, variables (including array elements) are in fact references (think pointers).

Given

```
type Animal is tagged null record;
type Dog is new Animal with null record;
```

you can of course say

```
type Plain_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Animal;
```

but then all the elements have to be `Animals`.

To get dispatching in Ada, you have to have a class-wide value to dispatch on, so you could try

```
type Class_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Animal'Class;
```

but then the compiler would tell you

```
gnatmake -c -u -f covariant_arrays.ads
gcc -c covariant_arrays.ads
covariant_arrays.ads:8:59: unconstrained element type in array declaration
gnatmake: "covariant_arrays.ads" compilation error
```

(`Animal` and `Dog` objects aren't the same size). You could try

```
type Access_Array is array (Positive range <>) of access Animal'Class;
```

which allows you to say

```
AA : Access_Array := (1 => new Animal, 2 => new Dog);
```

but then you're left with memory management problems, because Ada doesn't do garbage collection (at least, with any of the native code compilers I'm aware of). You could save yourself a lot of grief by using [`Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-10.html).

Comment: Great post. From my understanding this is what I have. `No, arrays are not covariant in Ada.  The problem is with the memory.  When the array is created in Ada it allocates a finite amount of space for each type of a specified object.  When you attempt to add a subtype element into the supertype array the computer will not be able give the subtype the amount of space necessary.  Java solves this by only holding references to the objects and object references are always the same size.`

Comment: "but then you're left with memory management problems" Not if you use the `ada.Finalization package` and correctly implement your `finalize` procedure.

Comment: @NWS: true, but OP might feel that came under the heading of "a lot of grief"!

Comment: @SimonWright True too... but stating that "_Ada doesn't do garbage collection_" is wrong so i thought it worth ponting out :)